# Spring config string format

Tags: spring

A stupid question on formatting but not able to figure out the correct negate parameter. I've the following string value which needs to be passed as a constructor arg through spring.

```
private final static String STRING_PATTERN = "\\<.*?>";
```

In spring config,

```
<bean class="com.test.TestBean">
<constructor-arg value="\\<.*?>" />
</bean>
```

As you can see, its not in the correct format. Can anyone please provide a clue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Spring config is an XML file

- there is no need to replace `\` with `\\` as in Java string literals
- you need to replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

So, you get

```
<constructor-arg value="\&lt;.*?&gt;" />
```